# apt gives weird error when writing `apt upgrade`

Tags: apt, upgrade, python

So im using Ubuntu 20.04 on WSL 2

I have deleted python using this way: `sudo apt remove python3`. After that, i wanted to install python again, which did work, but after installing i wrote `sudo apt update` and then `sudo apt upgrade` which after writing upgrade, it searches for upgrades but then gives this error:

```
nikeedev@Nikita-Goncarenko  ~ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
E: Could not read response to hello message from hook [ ! -f /usr/lib/ubuntu-advantage/apt-esm-json-hook ] || /usr/lib/ubuntu-advantage/apt-esm-json-hook || true: Success
E: Could not read response to hello message from hook [ ! -f /usr/lib/ubuntu-advantage/apt-esm-json-hook ] || /usr/lib/ubuntu-advantage/apt-esm-json-hook || true: Success
 ✘ nikeedev@Nikita-Goncarenko  ~
```

Comment: `apt` depends on Python. Which you've uninstalled. If you don't have anything important, you could reisntall. There also might be a way to reinstall Python, but I'm not sure how that would work in WSL2.

Comment: Ohh okay, I will try reinstalling it. I’ve noticed that apt maybe needed Python( which I soon understood right after uninstalling Python), but now I know it.

Comment: If you removed the only available version of Python, there is the possibility that you semi-broke the OS

Comment: Yes i know, but see answer that i marked as correct!

Comment: I have the same problem/error with 22.10 on WSL1. I didn't uninstall Python. If I type `python` it will start a Python 3.10 prompt. What can I do?

Comment: @TJJ if your python works there nothing to worry about. Does sudo apt update work?

Comment: @nikeedev Yes, update works without any errors/warnings. But upgrade causes this error and it won't proceed.

Comment: I had the same issue (and I did have python installed). After some googling, the most common solution seems to remove /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20apt-esm-hook.conf Beter backup the file beforehand. Refs: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/9269 https://moisescardona.me/fixing-apt-upgrade-in-ubuntu-22-10-in-wsl/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it working after reinstalling, thanks to [@cocomac 's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1383997/apt-gives-weird-error-when-writing-apt-upgrade/1393054#comment2387124_1383997)!

> `apt` depends on Python. Which you've uninstalled. If you don't have anything important, you could reisntall. There also might be a way to reinstall Python, but I'm not sure how that would work in WSL2.

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the same error after importing my old Ubuntu installing into a new laptop, but reinstalling Python didn't work for me. With guidance from [this Github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4640), I finally solved it by removing (well, renaming actually) the file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20apt-esm-hook.conf`:

```
cd /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/
sudo mv 20apt-esm-hook.conf 20apt-esm-hook.conf.bak
```

`sudo apt upgrade` now works like a charm :)